# Fastest way to code this fitness function?

Tags: r, math

I have the equation listed below in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbmx1.jpg). We are trying to code this in R in an attempt to then have it called by a genetic algorithm. The weights (wi, wj) are unknown and will be decided by the algorithm.

What is the fastest way to code this equation in R:

(Sum i=1 (mu i wi))/ (sum i=1 sum j=1 (sigma i j wi wj))

Image of the equation below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbmx1.jpg)

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please consider using the code notation for the code in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
mu <- c(4,7)
w <- c(2,3)
# numerator:
c(crossprod(mu,w))
# denominator
Sigma <- matrix(rpois(4, 10), ncol=2) # matrix of the sigma_{ij}
c(t(w) %*% Sigma %*% w)
```

If you want this quantity as a function of `w`:

```
f <- function(w, mu, Sigma){
  c(crossprod(mu,w)) / c(t(w) %*% Sigma %*% w)
}
```

Comment: thank you! This is to be used for a Genetic Algorithm so the weights are unknown, do you know how we would code with that in mind?

Comment: @Sisi95 Sorry I don't understand. Please edit your post and clarify.

Comment: I have editted the question, please let me know if you require further information.

Comment: @Sisi95 Sorry but this is not clear. Do you want to get this quantity as a function of the `wi` ?